# how to show last 3 records on the table if there are unknown number of record on sql sever

Tags: database

how to show last 3 record on the table if there are unknown number of records on sql sever. 
 for exam :
a table given a some records in which last 3 records show on table .
i have this query in which known records available :
 "select * FROM ( select Emp_ID, Salery , dense_rank()over(order by Salery DESC)rn from e1) WHERE rn >1 " but i want to got unknown number of records given a table , will be find last 3rd number  of records.

Comment: I simply dont get what you are asking. Please format the code parts correctly - and read [mcve] as guidance how to improve your input.

Comment: there is no such thing as 'last 3 records'.  you simply need to define a sort order and then you can filter